# While trying to create draft replies to threads using Gmail API, Original email content is not appended in the draft message

Tags: gmail-api

Title says it all

I have already implemented generating draft to a thread using gmail api document. Still,it doesn't work.

```
def create_message(sender, to, cc, bcc,inreplyto, subject, message_text, file=None, thread=None):
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['to'] = to
    if cc:
        message['cc'] = cc
    if bcc:
        message['bcc'] = bcc
    message["In-Reply-To"] =inreplyto
    message["References"] = inreplyto
    message['from'] = sender
    message['subject'] = subject
    msg = MIMEText(message_text, 'html')
    message.attach(msg)
    #if file:
        #message = attach_file(message, file)
    output =  {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode()}
    if thread:
        output['threadId'] = thread
    return output

#RFC format is followed as well
```

Suppose I have an email `"A"` in my inbox. Python script using gmail API creates a draft reply to this email which is stored as `"B"` in my inbox.

Expected
However, I want it to be stored in original gmail reply format which is -

```
"B
..."
```

and when you click the three dots, original email `"A"` should appear.

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail API doesn't have the feature that you wish. You would have to do it manually. I tried to do it manually, obtaining the message object i want to reply to and getting its body data. I concatenate the body data of the message with the structure that you're hopping for like this:

```
def createBody(message_text, inreplyto, replyName, replyBody):
    body = '<div dir="ltr">' \
           + message_text\
           + '</div><br>'\
           + '<div class="gmail_quote"><div dir="ltr" class="gmail_attr">'\
           + 'On Thu, Jul 18, 2019 at 11:06 AM ' + replyName + ' &lt;<a href="mailto:' + inreplyto + '">' + inreplyto + '</a>&gt; wrote:<br></div>'\
           '<blockquote class="gmail_quote" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0.8ex;border-left:1px solid rgb(204,204,204);padding-left:1ex">'\
           + replyBody\
           + '</div>'\
           + '</blockquote>'
```

You can check this structure by yourself using the "Try this API" feature of Gmail documentation [1].

I put this piece of code inside your create_message function to set the manually modified body to the draft message:

```
#create body
message_text = createBody(message_text, inreplyto, "name", replyBody)
msg = MIMEText(message_text, 'html')
message.attach(msg)
```

Here i get the message i want to reply to and the body of the message:

```
replyBody = base64.b64decode(service.users().messages().get(userId="me", id="XXXX").execute()['payload']['parts'][1]['body']['data']+'==')
```

For me it worked the structured draft, but i'm not being able to properly decode the replyBody data (In online tools does decode correctly but not in Python, don't know why). The other thing pending would be to find a way to obtain the name of the person you're replying.

[1] https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get